# Hamachi randomly disconnects in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, vpn, memory-leak

Logmein Hamachi + haguici on Ubuntu 20.04 randomly periodically disconnect, then you need to reconnect and input again your credentials, a real pain when gaming?

Fortunately, I found a fix, explained in the answer below.

Comment: What actually do you require?

Comment: @ThunderBird A way to stop it from randomly disconnecting, it is my internet fault, it is very good in all other situations. I found a solution explained in the answer below.

Comment: @ThunderBird it is *not my internet fault

Answer (score 0):

I found a great resource for this, just install the fix in this GitHub repository and it will work perfectly!

The fix fixes a memory allocation / accessing problem that older versions of Ubuntu where more lenient about, but the newer versions causes a crash when it happens:

Enjoy!
https://github.com/ejtagle/hamachi-fix-ubuntu20.04-or-newer/issues/2